# Show MessageBox when item was chosen from combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I started to play around with mvc.

I need the following: a combobox, when the user will choose one of the items a messageBox will pop up and will show "Please work this time!!!".

here my code:

**Index.html:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileName, Model.Files, new { Name = "map", @class = "form-control" })
```

**HomeVM:**

```
public class HomeVM
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Files { get; set; }
    public string SelectedFileName { get; internal set; }
    public List<string> DynamicAlgorithems { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowAllMobileDetails(HomeVM MV)
{
    string SelectedValue = MV.Files.Count.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("Please work this time!!!");
    return View(MV);        
}
```

The problem is: I can see all items in the combobox, but when the user choose one of them the MessageBox doesn't pops up.

Do you recognize what I'm missing?

Comment: You can't `MessageBox.Show` in asp.net mvc it is for winform.

Comment: So some other type of indication, alert or something

Comment: javascript alert("Please work this time!!!")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `MessageBox.Show` in asp.net MVC it is for `winform`.

Set `id='SelectedFileName'` `OnChange` event.  and use js `alert` function

You can use js to do it.

This is a jQuery sample.

```
$('#SelectedFileName').change(function(){
   alert('Please work this time!!!');
});
```

```js
$('#SelectedFileName').change(function(){
   alert('Please work this time!!!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectedFileName">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Or in your question, you can bind `onchange` event in the dropdownList directly.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileName, Model.Files, new { Name = "map", @class = "form-control" , onchange = @"alert('Please work this time!!!')"})
```

**EDIT**

Here is a ajax with asp.net small sample.

1. include jQuerylib in `Razor` page(html page)

   ```
   <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
        integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   ```
2. Binding `Onchange` event in `id='SelectedFileName'` dropdownlist.
3. Use [post](http://post) method to do ajax call, and use third parameter call back function to get `MVC` result.

look like this, you can do some logic in `ShowAllMobileDetails` action.

```
$('#SelectedFileName').change(function(){
   //get id="SelectedFileName"
   $.post('Home/ShowAllMobileDetails', $("form").serialize(),function(data){
        alert(data);
   });
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowAllMobileDetails(HomeVM MV)
{
    string SelectedValue = MV.Files.Count.ToString();
    // your logic

    string result = "Please work this time!!!";
    return View(result);        
}
```

Comment: I need indication from the homecontroller, is it possible do you think?

Comment: @Flufy short answer. NO and you shouldn't.

Comment: I'm looking the following: when the user choose some item I need to call to some method from the homecontroller, that's way I am trying to check that the index.html knows the homecontroller, i.e that the index.html tells the homecontroller: "Item was chosed"

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol, and each commit action is completely new. In your case you can use Js, if you need to do 
Cooperate with MVC you can use `AJAX`

Comment: @D-Shih can you plz show me how in ajax? I promise to voste & accept if so

Comment: Here is a video for asp.net MVC with jquery ajax https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBVsHuc3OIE, wish can help you, I will write a small sample for you

Comment: @Flufy I edit my answer and add some sample code about ajax.